# Extract href values with xpath on Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have this HTML:

```html
<a href="some content">Click here</a>
```

How can I extract `some content` and `click me` with `xpath` on Python 2.7?

So far i have the following ( extract only "some content" from href results):

```py
import lxml.etree as LE
import requests

r = requests.get("http://localhost")
html = r.text
root = LH.fromstring(html)
print root.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Comment: Do you have to use xpath?  A regular expression should work find for HTML.

Comment: I used to do it with with regex... but then i took an arrow in the knee.

Putting jokes aside. regex is not recomended to parse html/xml results :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm not familiar with xpath.  Maybe I'll give that a try next time I need to parse html.

Comment: xpath and lxml works pretty well. and its faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only select one or the other using XPath, but you could select all `<a>` elements and then pick off the `href` attribute and text content like this:

```
for elt in root.xpath('//a'):
    print(elt.attrib['href'], elt.text_content())
```